# Children’s stories about motocross

Tags: identification-request

I’m looking to find some books I read as a child: a collection of stories about a young boy involved with motocross or dirt biking. This was in the UK in the 90s. One of the stories featured a rival putting sugar in the protagonist’s petrol tank. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you remember anything more about the book? Was it a collection of short stories or could it have been a series of short novels? What time period did it seem to be set in (70s, 80s, 90s)? Was there anything unusual about how the protagonist acquired his dirt bike?

Comment: There were at least 2 separate books, each quite short. I can't recall any detail so I would expect the book was contemporary, set in late 80s or early 90s.

Comment: The only thing I've found close to this so far is Dirt Bike Racer by Matt Christopher. The books are much older than I remember, but could possibly be the ones I'm remembering.

Comment: Dirt Bike Racer was the one I was going to suggest. Matt Christopher also wrote one called  Dirt Bike Runaway, but I just skimmed through that one and it doesn't have an incident with sugar in the gas tank.